# How to make Java URI class to stop using a file

Tags: java, windows, swing, file, url

I have a small Java desktop application, it reads some image files and displays them. The problem is when I want to execute something (let me say, an exiftool operation) on these files, it denies because Java is still using them.

edit: This happens only on Windows, you can't write on an animated GIF file (converted to a URL object) which is being processed (being displayed) by Java, but on Ubuntu you can edit that file Metadata, system does not think the file is being processed.

Here is that part of my code.

I read the file;

```
ImageInputStream iis = null;
ImageReader reader = null;
iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(
                    f);
Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
reader = (ImageReader) imageReaders.next();

Path pathe = f.toPath();
String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(pathe);
ImageIcon icon = null;
```

Here is the part I process images, resize them and make JLabel to view them.

The reason why I am not just using Java ImageIO to fill that label with an image, ImageIO can only display the first frame of an animated GIF file. Converting an image to URL this way keep the image animated (even after resized).

```
ImageIcon icon = null;                    
Integer labelWidth = this.imageLabel.getWidth();
Integer labelHeight = this.imageLabel.getHeight();
URI img;
img = f.toURI();
URL umg = img.toURL();
icon = new ImageIcon(umg);

//some calculations for setting labelWidth and labelHeight here

icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(labelWidth, labelHeight,
                                                                  Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

At the end, streams are closed.

```
this.imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
iis.close();
reader.dispose();
```

And then I try to execute some exiftool commands via a process, it succesfully reads the image Metadata. But when updating the data, it says "Error renaming temporary file to C:/Users/path..." if the image is an animated GIF. 
No problems occur if the image is a non animated image, JPEG, PNG or GIF, it can read and update the Metadata, I guess .

When I cancel the image displaying part of the code, I can write on the image Metadata without errors. If I read a JPEG file and display it, still no problems. If I read an animated GIF and display it (animated, does it keep the file connection open?) no modifications on this file can be done, not in my program nor on cmd.exe while the debugging session is not closed. After I quit debugging, exiftool process on cmd.exe starts working normally.

Closing ImageInputStream or ImageReader did not help.

Is there a way to make Java process (if the file is animated, I use URI, URL classes) release the file after read operation? Do these classes I mentioned have methods for releasing, closing, shutting down, kill process etc. I need to read the animated images and display them animated and make update operations on them.

Comment: Are you on windows? Then I think it's the internal windows file access mechanism.It's like you send a file as an attachement in outlook, and windows holds the access until outlook is closed (regardless if the mail was send or not)

Comment: I highly recommend using [try-with-resources blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure things are being closed/disposed.

Comment: Hi @bish, yes I was on Windows 10 and after your comment I tried to execute my code on Ubuntu, it worked without problems. So it seems on a Windows system, Java locks a GIF file if it is being read as an URL object and being displayed but ignores a JPEG file. On Ubuntu, it does not care at all, you can do whatever you want on files being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the comments, here is the problem and the solution.

First of all I removed the unnecessary parts from the code. ImageInputStream and ImageReader were used to check image validation and detect image format (had to use different operations to GIF files) which I do not need anymore.

I still need to use File->URI->URL convertion to display animated GIFs. This is my old code.

```
URI img = f.toURI();
URL umg = img.toURL();
icon = new ImageIcon(umg);
```

This code kept connection to file open and blocked other processes editing the image file. (Only animated GIF files, on Windows system)

Here is the new code:

```
//these 2 lines are same
URI img = f.toURI();
URL umg = img.toURL();

InputStream is = umg.openStream();
byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; 
int n;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) 
{
baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
}
byte[] dd= baos.toByteArray();
icon = new ImageIcon(dd);
is.close();
```

With this approach URI(image) is read via stream and ImageIcon is created from image file's byte array not directly from URL, and after that operation InputStream is closed, so the block on that file is released. (If "is.close()" line is not executed, file is still being processed and blocked for other write operations)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load the image with [`Toolkit.createImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage-java.lang.String-) method?

Give this a go:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    private static class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        private Image i = null;

        public void loadImage(final File f) {
            //Most important point: load image via Toolkit.
            //I think it must support GIF, JPEG and PNG.
            i = getToolkit().createImage(f.getAbsolutePath());
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (i != null) {
                //g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this); //Draw full scale image.
                g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this); //Draw scaled/streched image.
                //Supplying 'this' in place of ImageObserver argument to the drawImage method is also very important!
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final DrawPanel imagePanel = new DrawPanel();
            imagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 350));

            final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

            final JButton load = new JButton("Load");
            load.addActionListener(e -> {
                if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(imagePanel) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    imagePanel.loadImage(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            });

            final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            contents.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            contents.add(load, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Images");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

1. There are several `createImage` methods to choose from.
2. I think they support animated GIFs, and non-animated JPGs and PNGs. I tested only for a GIF, but I have also worked with this in the past for JPGs and PNGs.
3. I think the animated image is completely loaded into memory (all frames). So you shouldn't have problem modifying the image after reading it.
4. Get the `Toolkit` related to the `Component` which will display the `Image`. I think also the `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit` should do the job under certain circumstances. Then use the `drawImage` method of the `Graphics` object to draw the image. There are several `drawImage` methods to choose from. You can you use for example the one that scales the image on the fly for you (by supplying new width and height along with the draw location). **Important**: make sure you supply the `drawImage` with the component which renders it as the `ImageObserver` (note `Component implements ImageObserver`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, before I try your suggestion I have created a solution for my case.

Comment: If you solved yourself your own question, then please post the answer here in order for others to know you did. And also post it because I'm curious to see how this can be solved (and I'm sure others will be too). Then don't forget also to accept your own answer when the minimum self-accepting time passes.

Comment: As soon as I found a solution, made my way back here to answer my question, just replied your comment first. Thanks again.